# Cannot find module but is already installed in current Project (xml-js, Windows)

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, node-modules

I'm actually working in a cross platform Project (Nodejs Package), all time I working under **Linux** platform, and sometimes I run the package on windows to test it. But for some reason in Windows I get "Cannot find module" error. That problem happen with 'xml-js' module, but the real strange situation happens when I init new clean package with 'xml-js' module installation. When I make a simple script that import the module, the error **not appears**. I really so confused and frustrated, because this only happens in Windows platform.

In addition, I tried by globally installation of package and obviously also locally installation of 'xml-js' module. Is not a syntax error, because in **Linux** the package working perfectly.

Previously I have working with "xml2js", and the same error been occurred. So I don't have any idea of the real problem.

If anyone wants to see the error, it's here …

```
Error: Cannot find module 'xml-js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\eduar\my-package\lib\src\tools.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**
Ok, by testing package I found a interesting thing. When I import the module in the root of project, this is correctly imported. I test my own package by other "clean" package creation. In the last I install my project (package) for testing but returns an error when my project tries to import the 'xml-js' module. I don't know if this error disappears once the package be uploaded in npmjs.com, but I don't want to upload a incomplete project only to test this problem.

Comment: Are you running `npm install` from windows for the windows package, or are the files being shared between linux/windows? If you have any native modules (interfacing with xml often results in native module usage in node), you need to run `npm install` from the OS before you run the code.

Comment: I decide to test it, every OS is different and sometimes you need to do specific things to avoid errors. In Linux you can simply install you package in other package for **testing** with the modules available in the 'new' package. But, in Windows you need first to run `npm install package-name` (xml-js) to install modules in your project to be able to use in other package for testing . PD: After this problem solution, other problems appears in the screen, but only are JavaScript's Syntax problems. So, always try to **test** your package in differents platforms, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try below command

**`npm i xml-js --save`**

then run again